# How to use multiple marks in vega-lite whem embedded into HTML?

Tags: html, vega-lite

I want to embed a vega-lite chart into a html page. It should draw a line chart with additional point symbols. However, it seems that the vega-lite code for multiple layers does not work when it is embedded in HTML.

My code that is working looks like the one displayed below. When I try to add layers like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816557/vega-lite-multiple-marks-in-a-single-charts), or try to combine two marks within one bracket like [HERE](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/line_overlay_stroked) it does not work. I am sure it is due to the HTML embedding but I cannot figure out from the [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/usage/embed.html) why it does not work.

Thank you for your ideas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Embedding Vega-Lite</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.25.0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5.9.1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.22.1"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vis"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var yourVlSpec = {
        $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json',
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        padding: 5,
        title: "Line chart of MMRM display",
        description: 'A simple line chart with embedded data.',
        data: {
          values: [
            {Time: 1, AVAL: 28, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 2, AVAL: 55, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 3, AVAL: 43, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 4, AVAL: 67, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 5, AVAL: 56, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 6, AVAL: 53, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 7, AVAL: 19, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 8, AVAL: 43, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 9, AVAL: 52, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 1, AVAL: 48, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 2, AVAL: 65, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 3, AVAL: 73, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 4, AVAL: 91, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 5, AVAL: 81, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 6, AVAL: 83, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 7, AVAL: 89, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 8, AVAL: 87, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 9, AVAL: 82, Treatment:'Intervention'}
          ]
        },
        mark: 'line' ,
            encoding: {
              x: {field: 'Time', type: 'quantitative'},
              y: {field: 'AVAL', type: 'quantitative'},
              color: {"field": "Treatment", "type": "nominal"}
        }
    }
        vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tested your spec without embedding? i.e. does it work in the online editor?

Comment: Thank you David, this helped! I realized that I had to separate the parts for 'mark' and 'encoding'. I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of David, I was able to track the error using the vega-lite online editor. The trick was to write a part for mark combining point and line descriptions. The encoding goes into a second code block. The working example (data is just imaginary) can be found below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Embedding Vega-Lite</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.25.0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5.9.1"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.22.1"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="vis"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var yourVlSpec = {
        $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json',
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        padding: 5,
        title: "Line chart of MMRM display",
        description: 'A simple line chart with embedded data.',
        data: {
          values: [
            {Time: 1, AVAL: 28, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 2, AVAL: 55, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 3, AVAL: 43, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 4, AVAL: 67, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 5, AVAL: 56, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 6, AVAL: 53, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 7, AVAL: 19, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 8, AVAL: 43, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 9, AVAL: 52, Treatment:'Placebo'},
            {Time: 1, AVAL: 48, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 2, AVAL: 65, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 3, AVAL: 73, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 4, AVAL: 91, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 5, AVAL: 81, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 6, AVAL: 83, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 7, AVAL: 89, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 8, AVAL: 87, Treatment:'Intervention'},
            {Time: 9, AVAL: 82, Treatment:'Intervention'}
          ]
        },
  "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "point": {
      "filled": false,
      "fill":  "white"
    }
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "Time", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "AVAL", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "Treatment", "type": "nominal"}
  }
    }
        vegaEmbed('#vis', yourVlSpec);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```